Comparing a function and its derivative
Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}   $ be defined by
$$
f(x)= \begin{cases} (1-x)^2\sin(x^2)  & \text{if } x\in (0,1) , 
 \\  0 & \text{otherwise}  \end{cases}
$$
And $f'$ be its derivative . Let
$S=\{ c\in \mathbb{R} : f'(x)\le cf(x)\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \}      $
Which one of the following is true ?

$S=\phi $

$S\neq \phi $ and $S$ is a proper subset of $(1 ,\infty )$

$(2 ,\infty )$ is a proper subset of $S$ .

$ S\cap (0,1)\neq \phi $


My attempt :-
Clearly $f'(x) \le cf(x) , \forall x \notin (0,1)   $ and for any $c$
For $x\in (0 ,1) ,f(x)\neq 0   $
$f'(x)=-2(1-x)\sin (x^2)+2x(1-x)^2\cos x^2     $
Assuming $f'(x)\le cf(x) $ for some $c$
$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-}  \frac {f'(x)}{f(x)}  =-\infty  $ which doesn't violate the assumption
$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac {f'(x)}{f(x)} $ is hard to calculate .
Trying to find maximum and minimum doesn't seem to work.
I am preety much clueless. Please guide me.

Divide $-2(1-x)\sin (x^2)+2x(1-x)^2\cos x^2\le c(1-x)^{2}\sin (x^{2})$ by $x^{2}(1-x)$ and let $x$ decrease to $0$. You will see that $S$ must be the empty set.
